# .NET own configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Is there any way that I could specify at runtime the configuration file I would like to use (other than App.config)? For example I would like to read a first argument from a command line that will be a path to the application's config and I would like my application to refer to it when I use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings (It's probably impossible but still it's worth asking).
I did find this piece of code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config
    = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.File = myRuntimeConfigFilePath;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

It works, but it overrides the original App.config's AppSettings section and my application isn't supposed to write anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this and it works. "path" is a path to configuration file.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not directly.

Indirectly, you could:

- spin up a second `AppDomain`, specify the config-file for that ([`AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx)), and execute the code in the app domain
- have two exes; the first (`foo.exe`) simply copies the config (into `bar.exe.config`) and shells the 2nd exe (`bar.exe`) [warning: thread race]

Comment: That is a big topic... basically, in .NET you have a level of abstraction inside a Process - the AppDomain. See msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb506139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using log4net you can specify your configuration file in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to refactor and create your own `ConfigurationRepository`. Then you can change at runtime what specific repository implementation you will use.

For example, `AppConfigRepository : ConfigurationRespository` will just be a facade for the old `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`.

Comment: I already know about it but i'm looking for something simpler so that I don't reinvent the wheel (if it exists ;))